# Set a date variable to SQL query in Python

Tags: python, sql, datetime, cx-oracle, data-retrieval

I want to do sql query in python. I could use cx_oracle to connection database in python:

```
# Build connection
conn_str = u'username/password@host:1521/sid'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve data from the database by using SQL query in Python:

```
sql_select_statement = """SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '20-oct-2017' AND '30-oct-2017'"""
```

Assume we don't know the starting date, we only have a date variable called starting_time, and its value is a datetime %m/%d/%Y. Also, ending_time is yesterday, I would like to modify my SQL query as:

```
sql_select_statement = """SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '20-oct-2017' AND sysdate-1"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql_select_statement, conn)
```

It works and generate a new df, but how to replace '20-oct-2017' with the variable starting_time? It's inside the sql query, and it's datetime format, so general python method like 'd%' % variable doesn't work. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: what about using string formatting? i.e. `"""SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN {st} AND sysdate-1""".format(st=starting_time)`

Comment: emmm..it says 'ORA-00905: missing keyword', maybe its format has to be modified. not sure

Comment: @kstullich ... forgot the quotes around the formatted string. But don't interpolate. Use parameterization.

Comment: @Parfait no I didn't forget the quotes, `starting_time` is a variable.

Comment: @kstullich ... inside the SQL you would need to quote: `BETWEEN '{st}'`

Comment: BETWEEN '{st}' works, thank you kstullich, thank you Parfait!!!

Comment: @HavenShi ... do note the quoted version is not recommended. Curious, did my posted solution using parameterization work? This method is the industry standard in working with SQL in application layer like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html) to connect pandas  and use the *params* argument of [`pandas.read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) to bind variable to SQL statement:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("username/password@host:1521/sid")

sql_select_statement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN :my_date AND sysdate-1"

my_var = '20-oct-2017'
df = pd.read_sql(sql_select_statement, engine, params={'my_date':my_var})
```

Alternatively, continue to use the raw connection with parameterization:

```
sql_select_statement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN :my_date AND sysdate-1"

my_var = '20-oct-2017'
df = pd.read_sql(sql_select_statement, conn, params={'my_date':my_var})
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy is not required to use parameters. You can use parameters with any database driver.

Comment: Correct @MartijnPieters. One can use SQLAlchemy or raw connection to pass params to [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html). I hope above did not imply it was only method. I recommended the use of SQLAlchemy as [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) usually prefer it with raw connection as *fallback mode* and especially if manipulating database with [`DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).