# Trying not to hardcode date range in SQL query (Python, SQL server)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am using Python to connect to SQL Server database and execute several 'select' type of queries that contain date range written in a particular way. All these queries have the same date range, so instead of hard-coding it, I'd prefer to have it as a string and change it in one place only when needed.
So far, I found out that I can use datetime module and the following logic to convert dates to strings:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime(2020,1,1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime(2020,1,31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Example of the query:

```
select * from where xxx='yyy' and time between start_date and end_date
```

How can I make it work?

EDIT
my code:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime(2020,1,1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime(2020,1,31).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@server/monitor2?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0")

sql_query = """ SELECT TOP 1000 
      [mtime]
      ,[avgvalue]
  FROM [monitor2].[dbo].[t_statistics_agg]
  where place = 'Europe' and mtime between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
  order by [mtime] asc;"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine)
print(df)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: That select query I wrote doesn't work written this way.

Comment: Try putting start_date and end_date in quotes. Also, print your query, and show your code. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Added my code to the post. It doesn't work in this form. However, it works if I simply use strings '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408557/pandas-read-sql-with-parameters for pointers on how to properly *and safely* pass parameters to SQL queries in Pandas. Depending on the type of your `mtime` column you do not need to convert the Python datetime yourself at all, because your driver will do it for you, if using proper placeholders and passing the params separately.

Comment: [Set a date variable to SQL query in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043508/set-a-date-variable-to-sql-query-in-python/47045041#47045041)

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for your input, I have found the answer to make the query work. The variables should look like:

```
start_date = date(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2020, 1, 31)
```

and SQL query like:

```
sql_query = f""" SELECT TOP 1000 
      [mtime]
      ,[avgvalue]
  FROM [monitor2].[dbo].[t_statistics_agg]
  where place = 'Europe' and mtime between '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
  order by [mtime] asc;"""
```